# When I want to paint texture the model becomes translucent white?

Tags: texture-painting

[image]

[image]
This is the model in the object model and edit mode.
[image]
But when I switch to texture painting model, the texture becomes this kind of white color.
I can't paint either.

Comment: hello, hard to tell, please share your file: https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: I share already

Comment: hello, you need to share the URL it will generate